RPI and microrendu
Currently, I use Rpi to store my songs (in BubbleUPNP server) and select the song at Rpi with VLC. Now, I would like to output the songs with DLNA/UPNP to microrendu. I found VLC can stream to Chromcast but not microrendu.
Please recommend what app install in RPI that can stream to microrendu?
Thanks.

try asking at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

If the microendu takes DNLA streams why don't you just use a DNLA server?
